# How to multiply columns of different dataframes based on conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, multiplication

I have 2 different dataframes, with the first dataframe containing values that I want to multiply with one of the values in the second dataframe, based on a condition.

So let's say my first dataframe contains of a long list with values between 1 and 10, and my second dataframe consists of the values `x`, `y` and `z`. Then I want to multiply the values 1-3 with `x`, 4-6 with `y` and 7-10 with `z`.

How do I accomplish that?

Example input:

```
df1          df2
1             x
2             y
3             z
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Desired output:

```
1x
2x
3x
4y
5y
6y
7z
8z
9z
10z
```

The actual dataframes are larger than this, but it's just an example.

Comment: Hi, would you mind including example input and output? This would make it easier for answerers to clearly understand what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have same rows in each data frames?

Comment: No the dataframes do not have the same rows.

Comment: I edited the main post for input and output

Comment: @Kaashoed you said "Then I want to multiply the values 1-3 with x, 4-6 with y and 7-10 with z." But what is the rule are you tying to apply?  three rows in data1 concatenated with the first row in data2, followed by next thee rows in data1 concatenated with the second row in data2 etc.?   Or is it the value <= 3 in data1 concatenated with  the first row in data2 etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you pass your dataframe threw a function somehow like this:

```
def newDf(df1, df2):
    df = []
    for idx, i in enumerate(df1):
        if idx <= 2: # 1st condition
            df.append(i * df2[0])
        elif idx <= 5: # 2nd condition
            df.append(i * df2[1])
        else:
            new_df.append(i * df2[2])

    return df
```